# Where does the Devil Fruit come from?

Tags: one-piece

Where does the Devil Fruit come from? I know that the Devil Fruits come from a tree. (Is this only a theory or really confirmed?)

Do all different Devil Fruits come from the same tree or from different trees as usual? And where do these tree/trees grow?

And how come that all Devil Fruits are scattered on so many different places in the One Piece world. How did they get there?

A special example would be the "Fire Devil Fruit".

*How and when did this Devil Fruit get on Dressrosa?*

Comment: Related: [Who cursed the Devil Fruits?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/11191/6166)

Comment: Related: [Where do devil fruits "grow"?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/33615/2516)

Answer (score 1):

There was an early claim that there is some magic tree that grows a Devil Fruit every thousand years or so.  Similarly, there are stories about the "Sea Devil" being the origin of the powers.  There is no real justification for these and they can be taken as in-story myths.  We essentially don't know if they are true or not.

What we do know is that when a Devil Fruit user dies, its ability is transferred to a regular fruit in close proximity. This is shown when the Salamander Fruit eaten by Smiley regenerated into an apple as it died. This regeneration cycle explains why all these fruits are scattered everywhere and how they continue to exist.

This does not explain where the fruits came from however.  It seems from out-of-universe statements by Oda that Vegapunk will soon (if not already I'm not up to date on the manga) explain the origins of the fruit.  This and the existence of artificial Devil Fruits indicate that more in depth knowledge about their origin and nature is known among the scientific elite of the New World.  This information has not, however, been revealed to the reader.

For the specific case of the Fire-Fire Devil Fruit: when Ace died, another piece of fruit of the same kind somewhere near Marine HQ became a Fire-Fire Devil Fruit.  This was eventually obtained by Doflamingo and brought to Dressrosa as a means to flush out Luffy.  As the military was in control of the battleground, I would expect they had fruit available to absorb the powers and gave this one to Doflamingo as part of the plan.  Alternatively Doflamingo or someone else could have carried fruit with them during the battle to collect the powers themselves.

Comment: When was it mentioned that they grow on a magical tree? To bring you up to date. He will supposedly fill us in at the end of the Dressrosa arc, which fyi is still a few months away.

Comment: @PeterRaeves well... please don't tell me yet... I plan to stop going on this site until I can catch up to find out that (in)directly from Oda.  I thought it was in the intro to a very early episode (maybe english dub only?) and even said there it was a legend.  I will re-find it tonight.

Comment: Apparently  it was mentioned as 50 years in one of fhe original pilots.  I doubt that is what i am remembering though.  If i find it again i will say it.  I doesnt matter though as it woild be early installment weirdness or a 4kids esk mistake.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a theory I came up with after watching a YouTube video covering the possibility that each Devil Fruit has its own soul. That theory is based on the idea that Devil Fruits have the souls of devils in them, which is why you cannot eat two Devil Fruits because the souls of the devils will fight with each other. This theory goes on to explain that the souls of the Devil Fruits influence the person who eats the DF, ex. Big Mom wasn’t super devious until she ate the Aoul Fruit. This could also explain the link between JoyBoy and why the Gomu Gomu no Mi is such an important fruit.

So, if you believe that DF’s have inherited will’s, you start to wonder where the original will comes from, who first imprinted their will on the DF? We know that DF’s popped up during the Void Century. We also know that during the Void Century, there was a giant war between a superpower country and 20 other countries which later became the World Government. So, what if the thing that sparked the war was the superpower country inventing Devil Fruits? What if they developed a way to create these Devil Fruits by imprinting the will’s of certain strong warriors into them? This new technological development would have made this country unstoppable, so these 20 kingdoms came together to stop them. Connecting it back to JoyBoy, you can theorize that his will was imprinted on the Gomu Gomu no Mi fruit, which is why the World Government wanted that fruit so badly.

My last point is that the Celestial Dragons consider themselves Gods, and they referred to their natural enemies as people with the Will of “D”, calling them Devils. Their original enemies were the strong lost kingdom who they would have referred to as devils, since they see themselves as being on the moral right side. Those “devils” created fruits that gave them immense strength, therefore they became known as Devil Fruits. And the people with the Will of “D” are the decedents of the lost kingdom who can unlock more from eating a Devil Fruit because their ancestors were the original creators.

This is my first time posting a theory, so sorry if it’s a little convoluted, I have just been thinking about this for a while and had to share it.