# Where do devil fruits "grow"?

Tags: one-piece

I don't remember, whether or not it was stated in the anime, where devil fruits grow. They always just "appear".

The only thing I know is that they can grow in any weather condition, because when Luffy meets Chopper he already has devil fruit abilities, but he never left the Drum Island in his life.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Devil fruits do not actually grow on trees. They are just normal fruits infused with a Devil fruit power. Based on its [wikia page](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Devil_Fruit):

> When a Devil Fruit user dies, their ability is reborn into another fruit of the same kind. Instead of growing from a plant, the ability simply regenerates inside another existing fruit, as seen when Smiley "died" and the Sara Sara no Mi, Model: Axolotl transplanted itself into a nearby apple. Another characteristic of a Devil Fruit's growth is that the stem becomes noticeably curlier than it was when the fruit was not endowed with the ability.

As stated, the only time we have seen such a process happen is in Chapter 676:

> [image]